# Need to split list into a nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

Im trying to make a sublist based on end of a line and #:
for example the file contains:

```
#
2.1,-3.1
-0.7,4.1
#
3.8,1.5
-1.2,1.1
```

and the output needs to be:
[[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1]], [[3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]]

but after coding :

```
results = []
fileToProcess = open("numerical.txt", "r")
for line in fileToProcess:
   results.append(line.strip().split(' '))
print(results)
```

i get :
[['#'], ['2.1', '-3.1'], ['-0.7', '4.1'], ['#'], ['3.8', '1.5'], ['-1.2', '1.1']]

Comment: Hi @AdilHusainFidaAli, welcome to Stack overflow.  The question is missing a few things that will help others help you.  For instance what language are you using?  What do you think needs to be done to the code to get the result you need.  What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Python as a programming language, and assuming you want exactly the output to be like this:

`[[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1]], [[3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]]`

Here is how to do it:

I commented the code for better understanding. Please tell me if something isn't clear.

```
fileToProcess = open("numerical.txt", "r")
results = []
hashtag_results = []

# For each line, we have two cases: either the line contains hashtags or contains numbers.
for line in fileToProcess:

    '''
    If the line doesn't contain hashtags, then we want to:
        1. Separate the text by "," and not spaces. 
        2. Parse the text as floats using list comprehension. 
        3. Append the parsed line to hashtag_results which contains 
        all lists between two hashtags.
    '''

    if not line.startswith("#"):
        line_results = [ float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')]
        hashtag_results.append(line_results)

   '''
   If the line contains a hashtag AND the hastag_results ISN'T EMPTY:
   then we want to append the whole hashtag_list to the final results list.
   '''
        
    if line.startswith("#") and hashtag_results:
        results.append(hashtag_results)
        hashtag_results = []

# For the final line, we append the last hashtag_results to the final results too.
results.append(hashtag_results)

print(results)

[[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1]], [[3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The general idea looks fine in your OP, but you will need to split by `","` (instead of `" "`), and append a `list` to `results`, where `list` is a list of the numerical values.

Another issue is that you don't close the file once you're finished with it. I suggest to use the built-in context manager construct (https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), which `open()` supports, and will automatically close the file once you leave the context manager scope.

Parsing data from file is a common data processing task in Python, so it *could* be achieved in a more "pythonic" way with a list comprehension.

```
# use a context manager, so once you leave the `with` block,
# the file is closed(!)
with open("numerical.txt", "r") as fileToProcess:
  results = [
    # split the line on "," and interpret each element as a float
    [float(val) for val in line.strip().split(",")]

    # iterate through each line in the file
    for line in fileToProcess

    # ignore lines that just have '#'
    if line.strip() != "#"
  ]

# here, the file would be closed, and `results` will contain the parsed data
# result = [[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1]], [[3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]]
```